# getting error as The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular

have a projejct that uses webpack .It is an angular project https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-8-registration-login-example
howw to generate service for that

When i used like this

```
ng g service rest-api
```

getting error as

```
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your project is missing a few key angular files... so technically your project isn't an angular project - did you create this project using the CLI?

The easiest way to fix this issue would be to follow the getting started tutorial here https://angular.io/guide/setup-local and create a new project and copy and paste the changes you've made in your project to the CLI created version.

Comment: is it possible to convert a webpack build to ng build.I am having trouble in running